Как использовать клиентскую библиотеку в Electron JS?
У меня есть скрипт, написанный на Electron (визуальная составляющая).
Как я могу добавить стороннюю библиотеку?
Библиотека: mineflayer
Мой package.json
{
    "name": "mine-bot",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "minecraft bot in the funtime",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron index.js"
    },
    "author": "Lotti - {t.me/tgluka}"
}

мой html
        <button id="connected_server" class="btn-window-style" style="right: 3%; bottom: 3%;">connected</button>
        <script type="module" src = "./../scripts/connect.js"></script>

мой js код
//тут как то нужно получить библиотеку mineflayer и обратиться к ней
const username = document.querySelector("#username_inp")

document.querySelector('#connected_server').addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (username.value) {
        //тут обращение к библиотеке
    } else {
        alert('Введите ')
    }
})

Я пробовал:

require (Не работает, потому что require не работает на стороне страницы)

import (Вроде не работает, но я не уверен, что всё правильно сделал, пробовал) import {name_metod} from 'mineflayer')



Почему вы решили, что не работает require и import? Может какие ошибки выдает?

Electron работает на примере web-a и выдает ошибку типо require not in definted

В моем коде работал require, но раз так.. то вам скорее всего нужно что-то связанное с ipc

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at connect.js:2:1 - ошибка при попытке require

вам нужно копать в эту сторону https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload
